# Neo4j too many WITH clauses - is it a good practice?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Everyone,

I have used Neo4j 2.2.3 to model a vehicle selling scenario. The structure of graph in brief is as follow:

Every vehicle is a node with label **VEHICLE** and have the following properties

1. Price
2. Mileage
3. Manufacture year

Everything else related to a vehicle

- Make (one node for each make, i.e. MAKE{make:'AUDI'}, MAKE{make:'BMW'}, etc.)
- Model (one node for each model, i.e. MODEL(model:'A5'}, MODEL{model:'318i'}, etc.)
- Fuel type (just like above, FUEL{type:'DIELSE'}, FUEL{type:'PETROL'},etc.)
- Gearbox (GBOX{type:'AUTO'}, GBOX{type:'MANUAL'}, etc.)
- Color (few important color nodes)
- others

There are fixed number of above nodes to which there are incoming relationships from **VEHICLE** nodes.

I allow users to search vehicles based on above criteria. User can search vehicle by **Price, Mileage, Manufacture Year** which are properties of vehicle hence, I don't need to lookup relationships and the query would look follow:

```
    MATCH (v:VEHICLE) WHERE  v.mileage >= 50000  AND v.mileage <= 100000 
AND v.price >= 5000 AND v.price <= 40000 RETURN v AS vehicle
```

OR search have more conditions as shown in the below cypher

```
    MATCH (v:VEHICLE)-[r]->(info) WHERE  v.mileage >= 100000 AND 
v.mileage <= 150000 AND v.price >= 90000 AND v.price <= 100000 
WITH v,r,info MATCH(v)-[]->(color:VCOLOR{name:'RED'})  
WITH v,r,info MATCH(v)-[]->(make:VMAKE{make:'TOYOTA'})  
WITH v,r,info MATCH(v)-[]->(plateType:VPLATE_TYPE{type:'-2'})  
WITH v,r,info MATCH(v)-[]->(cylinder:VCYLINDER{no:6})  
WITH v,r,info MATCH(v)-[]->(gbox:VGBOX{type:'MANUAL'})  
WITH v,r,info MATCH(v)-[]->(cond:VCONDITION{condition:'USED'})  
RETURN v AS vehicle,COLLECT({type:type(r), data:info}) AS details
```

The query is created dynamically based on the number of conditions the user include in vehicle search request. So if I see that user included a condition that is not part of vehicle node properties list (i.e. color or gearbox) then I add a **WITH** clause. The number of **WITH** clauses increase as the number of conditions increase (i.e. There could be up to 10 conditions).

Just wanted to know if I am using *WITH* clause properly? I find it tricky to wrap my head around *WITH* clause. At some point I would also have to implement paging functionality (not sure where to begin - maybe LIMIT keyword?).

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using the with and not directly the match?

Comment: So I an pipe the result of the first MATCH to the next MATCH and then apply the new conditions and so on until the last match, I will have a result set to which all the conditions are applied. Feel free to suggest an alternative approach, if you think would work best.

Comment: You can just use MATCH here. WITH is only needed if you need to aggregate something or if you're switching between queries and updates. Otherwise cypher can carry along results of MATCH/WHERE clauses just fine without WITH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cypher even removes WITH statements when planning your query.

IN DIFFERENCE, when you use `WITH distinct` or aggregation then you reduce the cardinality for following matches and that's something you WANT to do.

It doesn't really make sense what you do as you match the data multiple times?

If you want to run your query and then in the end provide *all* data for the vehicle, depending on the selectivity of your attributes,

i.e. **which is more selective, price and mileage or the other attributes.**
If you know which of the conditions is most selective, I'd use an index on that one, e.g. `USING INDEX gbox:VGBOX(type)`.

use either this:

```
MATCH (v:VEHICLE),
(v)-[:COLOR]->(color:VCOLOR{name:'RED'}),
(v)-[:MAKER]->(make:VMAKE{make:'TOYOTA'}),
(v)-[:GBOX]->(gbox:VGBOX{type:'MANUAL'}),
(v)-[:CONDITION]->(cond:VCONDITION{condition:'USED'}) 
WITH distinct v
WHERE  v.mileage >= 100000 AND v.mileage <= 150000 AND v.price >= 90000 AND v.price <= 100000 
MATCH (v)-[r]->(info)
RETURN v AS vehicle,COLLECT({type:type(r), data:info}) AS details
```

or this if mileage + price is more selective (note that I added relationship-types which are faster to check than **no rel-type** + label + prop):

```
MATCH (v:VEHICLE)
WHERE  v.mileage >= 100000 AND v.mileage <= 150000 
  AND  v.price >= 90000    AND v.price <= 100000 
WITH distinct v
MATCH (v)-[:COLOR]->(color:VCOLOR{name:'RED'}),
(v)-[:MAKER]->(make:VMAKE{make:'TOYOTA'}),
(v)-[:GBOX]->(gbox:VGBOX{type:'MANUAL'}),
(v)-[:CONDITION]->(cond:VCONDITION{condition:'USED'}) 
WITH distinct v
MATCH (v)-[r]->(info)
RETURN v AS vehicle,COLLECT({type:type(r), data:info}) AS details
```

I presume the second query will be faster in Neo4j 2.3 as you get index support for range queries (on price/mileage).

In Neo4j 2.2. the first might be faster, depending on the # of nodes you touch.

Comment: After looking at your db, I think as the first one will be more limiting, I'd use that in 2.2. You can provide the most selective attribute with USING INDEX.

Answer (score 1):

About the *WITH* normally it is used to pipe queries, performing some data modification before to pass it. I understand it, like a return which output needs to be passed to a new query (using aggregate functions or order and limits clauses before next match).

About your query, you are not doing anything with the *with* clause, just adding a new match. That can be done at the beginning. I find it more elegant. However, you can run a PROFILE to see how each one response (and if you can write the result I would thankful). I would expect to achieve a better performance running all the match before the where. You can also index the match property with the label *(i.e. CREATE INDEX ON :VCOLOR(name))* to achieve better results.

```
MATCH (v:VEHICLE)-[r]->(info), 
(v)-->(color:VCOLOR{name:'RED'}),
(v)-->(make:VMAKE{make:'TOYOTA'}),
(v)-->(gbox:VGBOX{type:'MANUAL'}),
(v)-->(cond:VCONDITION{condition:'USED'})  
WHERE  v.mileage >= 100000 AND 
v.mileage <= 150000 AND v.price >= 90000 AND v.price <= 100000  
RETURN v AS vehicle,COLLECT({type:type(r), data:info}) AS details
```

For your last question, pagination can be done using SKIP and LIMIT as you self suggested. An example can be found here: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-skip.html#skip-return-middle-two

Comment: Running the profile on query with **WHERE** clause ahead of matches produce the same number of db hits as query with **WHERE** as last clause though with query where **WHERE** is at the end the **projection** and last  **filter** show fewer rows.

Comment: then seems to be exactly the same. I have said that a **where** filter on non-indexed attributes should be slower when the set is bigger, since we need to scan more nodes. Running **match** at the beginning should reduce the number of nodes to be scanned. Was you set nodes eough? Thanks for sharing the results.

Comment: Putting *this* first is hurtful: `(v:VEHICLE)-[r]->(info), ` as it massively expands the scope for subsequent matches, it should be the last thing at the end.

Comment: is not "-[r]->" or "-->" the same?